# Haskell: replace characters in a string

Tags: haskell

First of all I'm very new to haskell and functional programming in general, so there might (will) be some very dumb mistakes in my code.

I'm trying to replace a few characters in a string with one or more different characters without using any libraries. The string could look like this "w1w1w8/w7w1w1//w". I want to replace every number greater than 1 with the corresponding amount of ones and the '/' with ten ones.

After reading a few similar posts, I came up with this:

```
replace x = 
    let 
        repl '/' = "1111111111"
        repl '9' = "111111111"
        repl '8' = "11111111"
        repl '7' = "1111111"
        repl '6' = "111111"
        repl '5' = "11111"
        repl '4' = "1111"
        repl '3' = "111"
        repl '2' = "11"
    in  map repl x
```

Well, it doesn't work and I would appreciate some input on this or even a way to achieve my goal. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stackoverflow. This is not so bad for a first question, but if you run into problems you need a more detailed description than "Well, it doesn't work"; Your question details should say what you want, what you did and what you observed (and how it is different from what you want).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, we can simplify the `repl` function by using `replicate`:

```
import Data.Char(isDigit, digitToInt)

replace x = map repl x
    where repl '/' = "1111111111"
          repl x | isDigit x && xi > 1 = replicate xi '1'
              where xi = digitToInt x
          repl x = [x]
```

Here `repl` this is a function that transforms a `Char` to a `String`. For the slash character, it returns a String of ten `'1'`s, for a character that `isDigit x`, then we replicate `'1'`, `xi` times. The last line means that all other characters `x`, are converted to a string `[x]`.

If we now use `map`, we will convert a `[String]` into a `[[String]]`. This is of course not what we want. But we can use `concat :: [[a]] -> [a]` to concatenate the sublists together:

```
import Data.Char(isDigit, digitToInt)

replace x = concat (map repl x)
    where repl '/' = "1111111111"
          repl x | isDigit x && xi > 1 = replicate xi '1'
              where xi = digitToInt x
          repl x = [x]
```

We can also use `concatMap :: (a -> [b]) -> [a] -> [b]`, and use an *eta reduction* to remove the `x` parameter from your `replace` function:

```
import Data.Char(isDigit, digitToInt)

replace = concatMap repl
    where repl '/' = "1111111111"
          repl x | isDigit x && xi > 1 = replicate xi '1'
              where xi = digitToInt x
          repl x = [x]
```

This then produces for your sample input:

```
Prelude Data.Char> replace "w1w1w8/w7w1w1//w"
"w1w1w111111111111111111w1111111w1w111111111111111111111w"
```

Comment: Your `replace` is "simpler" in the sense of *denser* when compared to OPs `repl`; but it's not going to be "simpler" in the sense of "easy to understand" for a complete beginner.

Comment: Thank you so much! That's really helpful and a better answer than I could have ever hoped for.

Comment: It's true that it is not super easy to understand, but I think I get most of it and will research the things I do not completely understand.

Answer (score 3):

You have two problems in your code: The first is that you only defined `repl` for /,9,8,7,6,5,3 and 2. What should happen if you encounter anything that's *not* one of those things? Whatever the case may be, you will need to add a case for that to your function definition.

The other problem is that what you want in the end is a `String`, but `map` is a function that takes a function from `a -> b` and a list of a `[a]` and returns a list of b `[b]`. Your `repl` function is of type `Char -> String`, so `map repl` is of type `String -> [String]` (instead of `String -> String` like you want). You'll have to "flatten" the list-of-list to just a list.

There's a prelude function called `concat :: [[a]] -> [a]` that does this for you; If you don't want to use predefined functions you can try implementing that yourself.